# How to set the number of maximum concurrent downloads in uGet?

Tags: uget

I am using [uget](https://ugetdm.com) on Windows. Is it possible to set the number of maximum concurrent downloads?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Click on Category, then Properties.
2. On the Active downloads box, set the number of concurrent downloads. Click OK.

[image: IMG:]